# convert milliseconds to time in R

Tags: r

I have a set of times in milliseconds that I want to convert to mm:ss (to compare with a similar set). For example I have

```
 x<-c(119254, 246973, 267492)
```

I can work out the minutes by the arithmetic

```
 > x/1000/60
 [1] 1.987567 4.116217 4.458200
```

Not sure how to get to %M:%S format, or if there is a proper way to take the milliseconds and convert without the arithmetic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the seconds to a DateTime object and `format.POSIXct` will take care of the calculations for display. You do not need to divide by 60 since POSIXct times are in seconds:

```
> as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+x/1000
#[1] "2013-03-07 16:01:59 PST" "2013-03-07 16:04:06 PST" "2013-03-07 16:04:27 PST"

> format( as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+x/1000, "%M:%S")
#[1] "01:59" "04:06" "04:27"
```

Comment: better use `format( as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(),tz="GMT")+x/1000, "%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: `Sys.Date()` is always GMT/UTC/UCT "underneath the hood" at least when it gets coerced to POSIXct by the "+" operator. It is only the console `print()`-ing that makes you think otherwise.

Comment: How to modify the function when converting from milliseconds to hours and minutes? any thoughts?

Comment: Multiply by 1000, convert back to POSIXct and then use format.